# MacBook Air 2018 typing wrong letter

Tags: macbook-pro

My Mac is typing wrong letters when I press button W it's typing WE , when I press E it's typing WE Likewise 2 =23, 3=23, C=XC, X=XC,  D=SD, S=SD,

I am using a MacBook Air (2018).

When I'm using a USB Keyboard I don't have this problem

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question! :)

Comment: Have you set the keyboard correctly?

Comment: If an external keyboard works ok, that's a good indication that the internal one is damaged.

Comment: @SolarMike  There's no keyboard setting which would ever produce the kind of stuff the OP is seeing.

Comment: Has your MacBook recently been repaired/opened? If the keyboard or trackpad was swapped the technician might have forgotten to run the keyboard mapper diagnostic (which sets the correct keyboard layout on the hardware-level)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you check your keyboard with OnScreenKeyboard. You can hit one letter C and see whether it is pressing on correctly or not.

**To enable the onscreen keyboard in case you don't see it:**

Open **System Preferences** and go to “**Keyboard**”, and look under the “**Keyboard**” tab

Check the box next to “**Show Keyboard & emoji viewers in menu bar**”

Pull down the newly visible Keyboard menu and choose “**Show Keyboard Viewer**”

After you conclude with this, you can try the following solution, it is a bit weird but have seen working for few people.

[**Weird solution**](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/94749/Keyboard+is+typing+the+wrong+character.)

Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You are eligible for free replacement topcases for any Apple laptop using the butterfly-spring design for four years from date of purchase. See their [Keyboard Service Program](https://support.apple.com/keyboard-service-program-for-mac-notebooks) page. The butterfly design is, frankly, not very sturdy, and if your fingers are more used to common-or-garden laptop or spongy desktop keyboards and mechanicals, then you're probably typing too hard.

I know of several folk now who have had six topcase replacements each, in less than twelve months.